# Show that |z+w| = |z| + |w| if and only if arg(z)=arg(w) for some z,w ∈ C, with z≠0 and w≠0?

Tags: complex-numbers

I honestly haven't got clue as to how to approach this, I've attempted to start by showing when $\Re(zw*) = |z||w|$ and have got that $\Re(zw*) = |z||w|$ when:

$$2abcd = a^2b^2+b^2c^2$$

but I have no idea where to go from here, or whether this is actually how I'm supposed go at it...

Although I have already proved that $|z+w| \le |z| + |w|$ if that helps.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: polar form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $z=Re^{ia}$ and $w=Se^{ib}$. Then we have $|z+w|=|Re^{ia}+Se^{ib}|=|Rcos(a)+Scos(b)+i(Rsin(a)+Ssin(b))|=\sqrt{(Rcos(a)+Scos(b))^2+(Rsin(a)+Ssin(b))^2}=\sqrt{R^2+S^2+2RScos(a-b)}$

This is given to equal $|z|+|w|=R+S$ i.e. we are given $\sqrt{R^2+S^2+2RScos(a-b)}=R+S$

Squaring both sides, $R^2+S^2+2RScos(a-b)=(R+S)^2=R^2+S^2+2RS$ implying $cos(a-b)=1$ i.e. $a-b=2n\pi$ for some integer $n$. Therefore, $arg(z)=arg(w)$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = r e^{i\theta}$ and $w = r' e^{i\theta'}$.

You have :
$$\begin{align}
|z+w|^2 &= |re^{i\theta} + r'e^{i\theta'}|^2\\
&= |r + r'e^{i(\theta'-\theta)}|^2\\
&= (r+r'\cos(\theta'-\theta))^2 + r'^2 \sin^2(\theta'-\theta)\\
&= r^2 + r'^2 + 2rr'\cos(\theta'-\theta)
\end{align}$$

Whereas :
$$\begin{align}
\left(|z|+|w|\right)^2 &= (r+r')^2\\
&=r^2 +r'^2 + 2rr'
\end{align}$$

Thus you have equality iff $cos(\theta-\theta') = 1$, ie $\theta \equiv\theta' [2\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

Square $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ twice.  You'll come up with $z\bar w=\bar z w$, hence $\frac{z}{\bar z}=\frac{z}{\bar w}$ (as $z$ and $w$ are not zero), i.e., the unit vectors in direction $w$ and $z$ are equal, what was to be shown.